# RStudio very slow to save Rmd Files

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown

I'm using blogdown to preview Rmarkdown files for a Hugo website.

RStudio is taking a long time to save Rmarkdown (Rmd) files.

For example, the file I am editing has a red title (meaning unsaved), and if I press the save button (or save all, or ctrl+s) then RStudio takes at least 10 seconds to save the file, and then it will start rending the .Rmd file ready for preview.

I've had this problem for quite a while. I've tried experimenting with different options.

I'm running Windows 10 on a Lenovo Yoga, and I've only recently freshly reinstalled Windows 10 and RStudio, so I don't think it is some larger problem with my machine.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem. It seems to have been because I had too many Google Chrome windows open which were using up a large amount of RAM (memory). This seemed to slow RStudio down. When I closed all my Google Chrome windows RStudio stopped having the problem with taking a long time to save.

Comment: 16BG. Why do you ask?